# how to find boolean in Mongoose DB?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have tried to find the cart which already paid or no, but it always return not correctly ,

let say that I want to find the Cart model which paid is false with user id 
but it showing the paid true for the result :(

to end point: 
this is my method

```
static async getCartspaid(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const getPaid = await Cart.find({
        user: req.user._id,
        paid: false
      })
      if (!getPaid) {
        res.status(204).json({ error: `can't found any` });
      } else {
        res.status(200).json(getPaid);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      next(e);
    }
  }
```

the result is list of paid true, that is result which I don't want, 
I just want the list which PAID EQUAL FALSE

Comment: did you set the datatype to boolean when you are setting the schema?

Comment: yes set it to boolean and default is false and I already update some to be true

Comment: try this 

await Cart.find({
        user: req.user._id,
        paid: {$ne: true}
      })

Comment: it same result :(, I did that also before, with $in also